# Symfony6: Set/update/manipulate environment variables (APP_ENV) with PHP (bootstrap.php)

Tags: php, apache, symfony, symfony6

We are in the process of reworking a Symfony5 application to Symfony6. We have a special case where the environment *APP_ENV* is dependent on the *hostname* of the app.

Accessing the same app via *app1.domain.com* and *app2.domain.com* should set the *APP_ENV* variable for symfony to *prod1* or *prod2*.

This used to happen in the config/bootstrap.php (a relic from Symfony4), but this is no longer available in Symfony6.

**Where is the best update-save place to inject some code to switch the variable before Symfony starts processing requests?**

The old portion in *bootstrap.php* looked something like this:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'])) {
  if(preg_match('#^app1\.domain\.com$#',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))  { 
    $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] = "prod1"; $_ENV['env_name'] = "prod1";
    $_ENV['env_name'] = "production_client1";
  } elseif(preg_match('#^app2\.domain\.com$#',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))  { 
    $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] = "prod2"; $_ENV['env_name'] = "prod2";
    $_ENV['env_name'] = "production_client2";
  } elseif(preg_match('#^app\.dev\.local$#',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']))  { 
    $_SERVER['APP_ENV'] = "dev"; $_ENV['env_name'] = "dev";
    $_ENV['env_name'] = "development";
  } else {
    die("invalid domain");
  }
}
```

Further switching happens within the app depending on the environment.

The following approaches do/did NOT work:

- setting the environment variable on the server (shared hosting) is not possible
- setting it via *.htaccess* does not work because mod_rewrite prepends *REDIRECT_* to all environment variables
- subscribers/listeners only attach at the request event (kernel.request), which is too late
- setting it in *.env* is static
- setting it in *.env.local.php* is not update save, as this file is generated
- running a file as a imported resource (*imports*) in *config.yaml* is also does not seem to work

This question is explicitly about switching the environment, not necessarily about a workaround! A nice bonus feature of this was that the same code could be run in the dev environment on the server just by accessing it via the local dev domain.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you are trying to do won't work. `APP_ENV` is used during container compilation, and cannot be on individual requests basis. Furthermore, not only won't work, but shouldn't work: Application environment cannot be made "request dependent", it's deployment dependent.

Comment: Have you tried moving the bootstrap.php code into public/index.php?  I know the new runtime component makes the startup process a bit of a head turner but it seems like you can still tweak super-globals before Symfony gets going.  The SymfonyRuntime.php code actually has a pretty good explanation of the startup process.

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. Why wouldn't you create a class for your settings, create a setting for what used to be the environment variable and refactor all the usages? Your code would improve in the process.

Comment: @Cerad putting it in index.php works, but I really do not know how safe/elegant it is to modify index.php with regards to future updates. I was hoping there is a more official way to do this, but if nothing else comes to light we will have modify index.php (maybe put it in an include file somewhere)

Comment: @MVKS It should be fine.  The reason why these sorts of files are in the app space is because they are intended to be modified.  The recipe stuff is also gradually improving and can actually tell you if a given file might need to be updated.  The older index.php lasted years and years without significant changes.  And the [runtime component](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-3-runtime-component) was specifically introduced to allow for changes without impacting the app space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we went with was to put the switching code into an include file in *config/* and load it directly from *index.php* before loading *autoload_runtime.php* and before creation of the kernel. Thank you to @Cerad for ensuring us that this would probably be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can use individual environment tweaks depending on the host. For example, choose the right database or other settings for the Symfony app without cloning it for each host.

You can also manage these configurations from another application, you can create a control panel for these settings. Like a hostprovider)

1. Create dir /env-configs
2. Create files /env-configs/app1.domain.com and /env-configs/app2.domain.com
3. Put the necessary environment variables in these files

> ```
> DATABASE_URL=mysql://root@127.0.0.1:3306/app1
> APP_CACHE_DIR=/var/cache/app1 
> APP_LOG_DIR=/var/log/app1 
> other .env vars
> ```

Just update index.php (Symfony 6.2)

```
<?php
use App\Kernel;

$_SERVER['APP_RUNTIME_OPTIONS']['dotenv_path'] = '/config-hosts/' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

require_once dirname(__DIR__).'/vendor/autoload_runtime.php';

return function (array $context) {
    return new Kernel($context['APP_ENV'], (bool) $context['APP_DEBUG']);
};
```

Enjoy!